# I have to make the 3 colors (red green blue) cover the original image, but transparently and vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css

The photo produced by my code has just 2 colors, red and blue, but the photo should be covered with 3 colors, red green blue:

How can I do it? I tried a lot, but I couldn't solve the problem. My picture looks like this:

[image: photo number 1 that is in my our code]

The picture should look like this:

[image]

```
// write your code here

var img = new SimpleImage('hilton.jpg');
print(img);

var imgW = img.getWidth();
print('Width: ' + imgW);

for (var pixel of img.values()) {

  if (pixel.getX() < imgW / 1.3) {

    pixel.setRed(255);
  } else if ((pixel.getX >= imgW / 1.3) && (pixel.getX <= imgW / 2.3)) {

    pixel.setGreen(255);
  } else if (pixel.getX() > imgW / 2.3) {

    pixel.setBlue(255);
  }
}

print(img);
```

Comment: This looks wrong: `pixel.getX`. You probably intended `pixel.getX()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're using incorrect divisions to split into thirds. You should be dividing `imgW` by 3 to split into three segments. Second of all, you typed `pixel.getX` rather than `pixel.getX()` in your `else if` for green pixels, so you were comparing a function to the value rather than the *return value* of the function:

```
var img = new SimpleImage('hilton.jpg');
print(img);

var imgW = img.getWidth();
print('Width: ' + imgW);

for(var pixel of img.values()){
    var third = imgW / 3;

    if(pixel.getX() < third){
        pixel.setRed(255);
    }

    else if((pixel.getX() >= third) && (pixel.getX() <= 2 * third)) 
    {
        pixel.setGreen(255);
    }

    else if (pixel.getX() > 2 * third){
        pixel.setBlue(255);
    }
}

print(img);
```